# WooCommerce: show the innermost subcategory

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to show the innermost subcategory of a product?
Examples:
If a product category is Devices -> Smartphones, I want to show Smartphones.
If it's Devices -> Smartphones -> Android, I want to show Android.
Thank you.

Comment: might look into this : https://gist.github.com/sectsect/306d2b2fc1f3d904126ffef22ed5e888